# Prove if $F(\sqrt[n]{a})$ is unramified or totally ramified in certain conditions

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $F$ be a complete discrete valuation field, $a\in F$.

(1) If $v(a)=0$, and the residue field $k$ is a finite field of characteristic $p$, if $(n,p)=1$, then $F(\sqrt[n]{a})$ is an unramified  extension of $F$.

(2) If $v(a)\geq1$, and $(n,v(a))=1$, then $F(\sqrt[n]{a})$ is a totally ramified  extension of $F$.

I think I should pass to the residue field and consider the polynomial $x^n-a$, but I do not know what to do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For (1) $x^n-a$ is separable in the residue field $O_F/(\pi_F)$ so $F(a^{1/n})/F$ is automatically unramified.

  Note that Hensel lemma gives that $\zeta_{q-1}\in F(a^{1/n})$ where $q$ is the cardinality of the residue field, and $x^n-a$ is separable in the residue field so Hensel lemma again gives that $a^{1/n}\in F(\zeta_{q-1})$ and $F(a^{1/n})=F(\zeta_{q-1})$.
- For (2) take $nl+m v(a)=1$, let $b=a^m\pi_F^{nl}$, $v(b)=1$, $F(a^{1/n})=F(b^{1/n})$ and $x^n-b$ is Eisenstein over $O_F$ so $F(b^{1/n})/F$ has degree $n$ and $v(b^{1/n})=1/n$, it is totally ramified.

Comment: Thank you very much!